# How can I detect the text size, and position using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, size

[image]

Here is a simple text on a web site, I would like to know what is the `My First Heading` length and height in how many pixel and at which position... How can I detect it via javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can use it, but prefer a prue javascript solution.

Comment: With jQuery it is easy. offset() return the absolute position referred to the document, while .css("width") and .css("height") the dimension in px.

Comment: you could use .position() with jQuery returns an object with left top of the elemnt

Comment: @SantiagoRebella that returns the coordinate referred to the sole container, not to the document

Comment: @JeanValjean but if the <h1> is not in any container does not returns top left from document? I was sure than yes :(

Comment: @SantiagoRebella All the displayed element have a position with respect to the top-left corner of the document. These coordinates are provided by offset(). If you use position(), you will get the coordinates with respect to the closest container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a temporary h1 element with display: inline style... and than get the offsetWidth.
try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var domId = 'dom-id' + Math.random();
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(temp);
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML;
    var width = null;
    var tempH1 = null;

    temp.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display: inline" id="' + domId + '">' + text + '</h1>';

    tempH1 = document.getElementById(domId);
    width = tempH1.offsetWidth;
    body.removeChild(temp);

    alert(width);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var header = document.getElementById("yourHeadingId");
var w = header.offsetWidth;  //Width
var h = header.offsetHeight; //Height
var x = header.offsetLeft;   //Top left corner x position.
var y = header.offsetTop;    //Top left corner y position.
```

To change the header's content:

```
while(header.firstChild) {
    header.removeChild(header.firstChild);
}
header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some new content"));
```

Comment: If I would like to have `My First` only, is this possible to do so ?

Comment: You could set the text to `"My First"`, then get the values like I posted, and set the text back.
Other than that, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

`element.offsetWidth`/`element.offsetHeight` for the element dimensions.
`element.offsetTop`/`element.offsetLeft` for the top left corner location (relative to its [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetParent)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` to calculate the values. Like

```
document.getElementById("DOMID").clientWidth
```